# How to get all the menu listed in Menus Created inside the Apperance Menu?

Tags: menus

I'm creating a custom menu widget in wordpress using

```
$menu_slug = 'my-menu-slug'
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu' => $menu_slug,
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-collapse',
    'walker' => new Sunset_Walker_Nav_Primary()
  ) );
```

the problem is i'm having trouble on getting the menu slugs

[image: the menus i want to retrieve is under here]

Answer (score 0):

its been answered by Math Royal [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145094/override-custom-menu-widget) but the difference is he use the name of menu instead of slug